# Extend background to the bottom of the page, scroll or not

Tags: html, css

I need to have background extending to the bottom of the page, and it should work with both short and long pages.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="container">Container of variable height</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
    background: url("background.jpg");
}
#container {
   margin: auto;
   width: 800px;
}
```

That's the general structure. Background works fine on long pages with a scroll, but on short pages it cuts off right below #container.

If I add

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

It will extent do the bottom on short pages, but if you scroll on long pages, background cuts out in the middle.

I tried using

```
html, body {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

But it's just ignored by all browsers

What can I do make background work both on long and short pages? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can play around with the various [background-size](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/backgrounds-borders/size.html) css properties. e.g. assuming your background image's size is quite large and does not need tiling:

```
body {
    background: url("background.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Definitely the easiest way. I often end up going with something like `{background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover}`.

Comment: nope, this doesn't help. Body tag still cuts off right under the container.

Answer (score 0):

USe:

```
body {
  background-image:url('background.jpg');
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```